# Query for child nodes

Tags: nodes, 7

On any node in Drupal 7, I want to show a list of its child nodes.  How do I do this?  I basically want to create my own navigation system.

I'm still unfamiliar with the terms in drupal 7. I establish the hierarchy of nodes via the following steps:

1. go to admin dashboard menu and click on "Add content"
2. select the "Page" content type
3. fill out the fields
4. under "Menu settings," I select "Provide menu link"
5. I choose the parent node under the "Parent item' drop-down menu
6. save and publish

Comment: The question is quite vague. How do you define a page as child of another one? Are you referring to nodes, or something else?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - ok i added more info

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, there is no concept of sub pages or child nodes in Drupal. What you refer to is the [menu](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu) structure used for navigation. A node can have a menu items *linking* to it and menu items can be organized hierarchically. The system was not designed to create and define relation between nodes, but only for navigation. If you look at [the API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/7), there is no simple way to retrieve the children of a menu item.

The [book module](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book) included in Drupal core can be used to create a hierarchical structure for nodes. There are other options such as the [relation](https://drupal.org/project/relation), [references](https://drupal.org/project/references) and [node hierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) modules.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the [Node Hierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) module to manage the parent/child relationships, and then create a view that displays the child pages using the Views integration built into Node Hierarchy. This view could then be embedded in each parent using the [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module.

Answer (score 0):

The option "Menu settings->Provide menu link" is not creating a relation between nodes, it is just the reference to the menu system. If you want to make some reference between nodes you should use the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) Module, but it probably not what you want.

before the navigation, you should concept a structure of your site, than you will see which is the easies to create your [navigation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu).